# Search Box with autocomplete jQuery - Update

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to implement Instant Search Box with autocomplete (jQuery). The data is being fetched from database. I can see it is getting through but for some reason autocomplete is not working.

### HTML

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label style="color: white" for="searchBar">Skills: </label>
  <input id="searchBar">
</div>
```

### PHP - Slim framework

```
$app->get('/ajaxsearchbox', function() {

    //$query = $_REQUEST['query'];
    $query = $_GET['query'];

    if (isset($query)) {

        $sql = DB::query("SELECT * FROM players WHERE playerName LIKE '%$query%'");

        foreach ($sql as $result[]) ;
    };
    echo json_encode(array("result" => $result));
});
```

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#searchBar" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.getJSON("/ajaxsearchbox",{ query:request.term},response);
    },
    minLength: 0   
  });   
})
```

Comment: Could you print the output returned by your get request. If you want autocomplete to work without customisation. Your get request should return JSON in this format - `[{id:'some id',value:'somevalue',label:'some label'},{same format as the first element}]`

Comment: This is what i am getting.

Comment: {"result":[{"id":"2","playerName":"S.Crosby","teamName":"Penguins","scoreChange":"4.59","category":"rookies","salary":"9000000","valueAssesment":"1500"}]}

Comment: I need to print the ,"playerName":"S.Crosby"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your Get request return simpler data

```
$app->get('/ajaxsearchbox', function() {

    //$query = $_REQUEST['query'];
    $query = $_GET['query'];

    if (isset($query)) {

        $sql = DB::query("SELECT * FROM players WHERE playerName LIKE '%$query%'");

        foreach ($sql as $result[]) ;
    };
    echo json_encode($result);
});
```

after this Add custom rendering in your Jquery autocomplete like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#searchBar" ).autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.getJSON("/ajaxsearchbox",{ query:request.term},response);
        },
        minLength: 0,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#searchBar" ).val( ui.item.playerName );
        },
    }).autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
       return $( "<li>" )
       .append( "<div>PlayerName : " + item.playerName + "</div>" )
       .appendTo( ul );
     };
   } );

}
```

)

check this link to know more about handling custom data http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

Comment: How can I do it? Whenever I click the up arrow nothing happens.